# Проблемы с созданием объекта при использовании Proxy.newProxyInstance()

Tags: java

Всем привет.
Столкнулся с проблемой. Объект создаётся через Proxy.newProxyInstance().

Вот весь код:

```
public class NewAPIHolder {

    private static GeneralAPI generalAPI =
            (GeneralAPI) Proxy.newProxyInstance(
                    GeneralAPI.class.getClassLoader(),
                    GeneralAPI.class.getInterfaces(),
                    new CFHandler()
            );

    public static ContestAPI getContestAPI() {
        return generalAPI;
    }
    public static ProblemsetAPI getProblemsetAPI() {
        return generalAPI;
    }
    public static UserAPI getUserAPI() {
        return generalAPI;
    }

    private abstract class GeneralAPI implements ContestAPI, ProblemsetAPI, UserAPI {}
}
```

На строке с инициализацией generalAPI выбрасывается

> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0 cannot be cast to
>   api.interfaces.NewAPIHolder$GeneralAPI

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку `GeneralAPI` - это класс, то не существует способа создать для него прокси при помощи `Proxy`. Но зачем он вам вообще нужен?

```
public class NewAPIHolder {

    private static Object generalAPI =
            Proxy.newProxyInstance(
                    NewAPIHolder.class.getClassLoader(),
                    new Class<?>[] { ContestAPI.class, ProblemsetAPI.class, getUserAPI.class },
                    new CFHandler()
            );

    public static ContestAPI getContestAPI() {
        return (ContestAPI)generalAPI;
    }
    public static ProblemsetAPI getProblemsetAPI() {
        return (ProblemsetAPI)generalAPI;
    }
    public static UserAPI getUserAPI() {
        return (UserAPI)generalAPI;
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, проблема уже решена.
Этот класс мне нужен был для того, чтобы избежать лишних кастов (как вы написали, например).
Нужно было сделать `GeneralAPI` интерфейсом, наследующим все остальные, а при вызове Proxy.newProxyInstance() передавать вторым аргументом `new Class<?>[]{GeneralAPI.class}`

Всё равно спасибо за отклик